# Given $x+\frac{1}{x}=3$ & $x^{4}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}=40$. Determine the value of $x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{4}}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have tried out many approaches including solving the first equation for $x$ and applying algebraic identities but none worked.This problem seems to have errors.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct.  The conditions on $x$ are impossible.  If $x + \frac{1}{x} = 3$, then $x = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$, but this would imply $$x^4 + \frac{1}{x^2} = 9(3 \pm \sqrt{5}),$$ neither of which is $40$.

Answer (score 2):

There has to be a mistake in the problem.  The first equation $x + \frac{1}{x} = 3$ implies that $x \ne 0$ and therefore
multiplying through by $x$ we get $x^{2} + 1 = 3x$ so $x^{2} - 3x + 1 = 0$ which has roots $(3 \pm \sqrt{5})/2$ using the quadratic formula.  But neither of those satisfies the second equation.

Answer (score 1):

The two equations $x+\frac1x=3$ and $x^4+\frac1{x^2}=40,$ respectively equivalent to
$$P(x):=x^6-40x^2+1=0\quad\text{and}\quad Q(x):=x^2-3x+1=0,$$
are incompatible indeed, since the two polynomials $P$ and $Q$ are coprime, by the Euclidean algorithm:

$$P(x)\equiv R(x):=24x-14\bmod{Q(x)}$$
and
$$Q(x)\equiv59/144\bmod R(x).$$